# Sentinel work fail after rename config command of redis

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I've installed stablest redis(ver 3.2). Everything work fine until I renamed CONFIG command of redis, sentinel could not promote slave to be master.
Think the problem is sentinel still use CONFIG command (has been renamed) to change configuration of redis.
Is there any way to change configuration of sentinel (via redis-cli or configuration files sentinel.conf) to adapt redis configuration (renamed config command). If there isn't, how about changing source code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After google, I found solution for this problem.
I replace **redis/src/sentinel.c** via this [redis github](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/2068/files#diff-45b8aaf53e1ac2b9134c1e0ad96a0e03), rebuild and install redis from source.

Then I could add a directive to sentinel.conf to configure sentinel use renamed config command.

```
sentinel config-command mymaster <renamed-command>
```